# Uploading to Google Cloud Storage not working even after enabling CORS

Tags: cors, google-cloud-storage

I have updated this cors.json to GCS bucket:

```
[
  {
    "origin": ["*"],
    "method": ["GET", "POST", "HEAD", "DELETE", "PUT"],
    "responseHeader": ["Content-Type"],
    "maxAgeSeconds": 3600
  }
]
```

using:

```
gsutil cors set cors.json gs://my-bucket
```

I have checked the preflight response:

```
access-control-allow-headers: Content-Type
access-control-allow-methods: GET,POST,HEAD,DELETE,PUT
access-control-allow-origin: *
access-control-max-age: 3600
```

Yet, the POST request to upload the file with this header:

```
:authority: storage.googleapis.com
:method: POST
:scheme: https
accept: */*
accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br
accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.9,ta;q=0.8
content-length: 913
content-type: application/json
dnt: 1
origin: https://099e00581bf2.ngrok.io
```

fails because of CORS error:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://storage.googleapis.com/...' from origin 'https://099e00581bf2.ngrok.io' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: in method, add "OPTIONS" as well? I think?

Comment: Tried it, but didnt work :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the answer to this problem. I was using "POST" method instead of "PUT". Since I created the signed url using **action: 'write'**

```
gcsfile.getSignedUrl({
    action: 'write',
    contentType: req.body.contentType,
    expires: Date.now() + 1000 * 60 * 60
})
```

I should be using "PUT" method, while calling https://storage.googleapis.com. Once I changed it, it worked like a charm.

But, this CORS error is so misleading. Hope GCS throws some meaningful error message in the future.

Answer (score 4):

- Start with this, just to cut all the possible causes from the list:

```
[
  {
    "origin": ["*"],
    "method": ["*"],
    "responseHeader": ["*"],
    "maxAgeSeconds": 3600
  }
]
```

- Clear all the caches on your side.
- Wait for 1-2 hours: the effects might be delayed due to intermediary caches as well.
- Try again.
- If it works, narrow down the **SUPER** permissive CORS conf that you created at step 1, by adding the methods that you want to be allowed, the origins and the response headers

---

If the steps above still don't solve your problem I would consider lecturing these two resources:
https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/configuring-cors#storage-get-bucket-metadata-nodejs
https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/configuring-cors#troubleshooting

Comment: adding "responseHeader" fixed it for me! I didn't need to wait or refresh cache, it started working immediately.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of using a pre-signed url approach you can try using REST API with an access token using POST request.

Here is the reference:

https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/uploading-objects#rest-upload-objects

To generate access token :

```
gcloud auth print-access-token
```

Comment: Thanks! But, this will expire after some time. Also, it is not a good idea to give out your token with longer expiry for anonymous file uploads.

Comment: Ideal expiry time is 60 minutes but it is configurable. So I don't see any harm in using it. https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account#jwt-auth